# Script execution while stopping the amazon ec2 linux instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to execute one shell script while stopping the EC2 linux instance from amazon web consol. But it's not executing.

Can  any one help me as early possible, how to execute script while stopping the instance.

Thanks in advance.

With Regards,
Krishna Bhaskar.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to execute one shell script while stopping the EC2 linux instance from amazon web consol. But it's not executing.

Perhaps it's not executing because you're stopping the instance. This is the most obvious behavior to expect.

Could you provide more details about what you've done to the instance to make it so that this sort of thing would even work?

Comment: Hi, I have created one script named as tomcat with below content.   #!/bin/sh
# Baseline Apache Tomcat start/stop script
#
# chkconfig: 345 80 20
# description: Apache Tomcat

case $1 in
start)
        /bin/su -s /bin/sh -l tomcat -c /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
stop)
        /bin/su -s /bin/sh -l tomcat -c /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
        ;;
esac
exit 0   and placed it in init.d folder. While starting the instance tomcat startup script executing, but while stopping instance tomcat shutdown script not executing.  Please let me know how to maket it execute. I tried with shutdown cmd

Comment: I tried with shutdown command in linux terminal also, then also not executing tomcat shutdown script.